# NHibernate: returning a strongly typed list having applied an aggregate function

Tags: nhibernate

I'd like to have nHibernate return a strongly typed list from a CreateQuery invocation using HQL.

We'd like a strongly typed list of "MyType" returned, but we'd like to apply an aggregate function to the resultset before it's returned. Unfortunately, as I understand it, adding the aggregate field means nHibernate is unable to match the results to the signature of our "MyType" type.

How do we get around this? The following query describes what we'd like to return from the database - but the "feedcount" field affects nHibernate's ability to determine the typed list to return.

```
select feedname, count(feedurl) as feedcount from rsssubscriptions group by feedurl, feedname order by feedcount desc
```

Presumably the resultset has to be generated earlier in the sequence of events, to ensure nHibenate can infer the correct type to instantiate for each record.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to do:

```
IList<MyObj> reults = Session.CreateQuery("select r.feedname as feedname, count(r.feedurl) as feedcount from rsssubscriptions r group by r.feedname")
                            .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(myobj)))
                            .List<MyObj>();
```

And then define the MyObj type like this:

```
public class MyObj 
{
    public virtual long feedcount { get; set; }
    public virtual string feedname { get; set; }
}
```

The property names of the above type must be the same as the aliases of your returned properties and all properties must be virtual.

Read the following post on more info on what you can do with the SetResultTransformer() method:
http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/nhibernate-setresulttransformer-and-dto.aspx

Comment: It's also possible use a constructor with HQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603608/nhibernate-hql-how-to-use-the-new-object-constructor-with-distinct , http://ayende.com/blog/1218/underused-nhibernate-feature-creating-objects-in-the-select-clause and http://averyblog.com/net/refactoring-using-object-constructors-in-hql-with-nhibernate/