# NHibernate: Lazyload single property

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have currently moved my blogengine over from Linq2Sql to NHIbernate.

I'm stuck at the following performance problem:
I got one table: 'Posts', that has Id, Title, PostContent, DateCreated collumns and so on.

The problem is that, when I'm creating the "Recent posts list", I don't want the whole `PostContent`.

In Linq2Sql you can set lazy loading on a single property, so it won't be part of the SQL query until you actually ask for the property.

I tried doing this with Fluent NHibernate, by doing this:

`Map(x => x.PostContent).LazyLoad();`

It didn't work out. Googling around, it seems that NHibernate doesn't support this, so my question is, how can I fix this?

Is it really not possible to lazy load my property without moving the content to a seperate table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have also tried to create a class called PostContent with a value property inside, and map it using this:
Component(x => x.PostContent, m => m.Map(x => x.Value).Column("PostContent")).LazyLoad();

Didn't work either :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: this capability is now available in the NHibernate trunk.

See details on [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx), where the sample is *exactly* the scenario you describe here.

Comment: what does it mean when it says "it is currently only available when using the Castle Proxy Factory."?

Comment: @Louis NHibernate can be configured to use either Castle.DynamicProxy or LinFu.DynamicProxy. You are almost certainly using Castle already.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can achieve what you want (kind of lazy loading but not the same)

```
var posts = NHibernateSessionManager.Session.CreateQuery("Select p.Id as Id, p.Title as Title, p.DateCreated as DateCreated from Post p")
                .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Post)))
                .List<Post>();
```

What the AliasToBean is intended for is, doing selects for specific columns (usually from more than one entities) and return a strongly typed collection instead of a System.Object[].

Now if you Bean (class) is your Post class then it will popultate to that class ONLY the requested columns and nothing else.

What you will NOT be having though is a collection of NHibernate managed objects. All Posts in the returned lists are detached non controlled objects.

For doing things like "getting all recent posts" without having to get the most "heavyweight" columns of your entity while not having to create other classes to convert the data to, the above solution is kind of perfect.

Check this out for more info:
[NHibernate: returning a strongly typed list having applied an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797920/nhibernate-returning-a-strongly-typed-list-having-applied-an-aggregate-function/)

Comment: Thanks! This really moved me forward. Btw, sorry for the slow reply.
I was wondering how I should handle caching with this approach? As I understand, I can't cache anything in the 2nd layer cache, if its detached, like you say.

Comment: No problem... I believe these objests are still getting in tht 2nd level cache. As I am not sure about that maybe you can find out by trying it with a test (unit test or just by debugging a second request to the same code to see if the query hits the database again or not - of course cache should be enabled in the Post mapping file).

Comment: I did this actually, and it seems that as soon I use ResultTransfomer, the collections get uncacheable :/

Comment: One thing to add that is important with the query above, is ensure you have aliases or you'll get "Could not find a setter for property '0' in class"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible when PostContent is mapped to the same table, because the performance difference is not significant in 99% of the situations. When you are in the 1%, you can consider using handbuild sql instead of a orm for that case.

Lazy/Eager loading is not possible at all with linq to sql (out of the box) as far as I know.

What you can do create a different class with the data you want to select and just select that data into a new object.

Comment: Hmm okay. Sounds like a solution. Can you make a small example of how you would do it?

Comment: Lazy/Eager loading *is* possible with LinqToSql.  It's just less flexible than NHibernate.

Comment: First, I would start a profiler and find the slowest part of the code. Than I would optimize that part first. Than repeat until fast enough. When fast enough is under 1/1000th of a second, I would hit the part of the query, that I would write like session.Linq<Post>().Select(post => new RecentPost(post.Property1, post.Property2).Take(10).ToList();

Comment: As requested, a good (almost identical) example for what you want to do, at least regarding setting up the mappings, is here: http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/17/lazy-loading-blobs-and-the-like-in-nhibernate.aspx