# NHibernate HQL: How to use the new object constructor with 'distinct'?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I need to use the **HQL object constructor feature**, e.g:

```
select new SomeClass(i.Id, i.Name) from Item i...
```

But I **also** need to use the **`distinct` keyword**, as there are joins further down in the query, e.g.:

```
select distinct i.Id from Item i
```

I have tried this: but it just causes an Antlr exception, so I assume it's invalid syntax:

```
select new SomeClass(distinct i.Id, i.Name) from Item i
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984135/hibernate-new-keyword-with-distinct

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it looks like this works:

```
select distinct new SomeClass(i.Id, i.Name) from Item i...
```