# Hibernate new keyword with distinct

Tags: hibernate, hql, new-operator, distinct

I need to take hql that is currently :

```
select distinct a from Asset as a where ...
```

and change it to

```
select new com.org.AssetDTO(a.id, a.address, a.status) from Asset as a where ...
```

My problem is with the distinct keyword.  Where does it belong in an hql query where you're using the new Object query type.  One thought was to use a sub-select and have my distinct there.  I've tried adding `distinct a.id` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok for anyone interested the proper syntax is

```
select distinct new com.org.AssetDTO(a.id, a.address, a.status) from Asset as a where ...
```

Comment: Does this mean the result of your query, is not affected by the AssetDTO equals() method?

Comment: Why would the results of the query be affected by the equals() method?  Perhaps I'm not understanding your question

Comment: `distinct new com.org.AssetDTO` is equivalent of `distinct a from Asset` and  not equivalent of `distinct(a.id, a.address, a.status)`. All the fields of the entity are used in selecting the DISTINCT?

Comment: select distinct new com.org.AssetDTO(a.id, a.address, a.status) from Asset as a is the same as a normal sql select statement of select distinct a.id, a.address, a.status from Asset a and then providing a RowMapper to turn that into an array of DTO's, this syntax is/was the HQL equiv. of that

Comment: but what if i need more columns then i need in distinct clause? ex, if i want distinct only on (a.id, a.address) but i need the data also of a.status